# is there any work around for "django-admin makemessages" not to make changes to already updated translations?

Tags: python, django, translation

I have added a translation for my web app a few months back but added some new changes now. For which also I needed to make the translation. But they are variables like Django messages and notifications. I tried adding the translation for them in existing PO files and compiled them. But not getting translated. So do I need to generate new po files using make messages command? I tried it. but it also brings changes to already translated files. is there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `django-admin compilemessages` to generate new `.mo` files. Like this:

```
 django-admin compilemessages --locale=pt_BR
```

More information can be found in the [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#compilemessages).

Comment: yes i have i done that also but messages not getting translated

Comment: did you restart the server?

Comment: yes i have restarted...currently i am testing it on my local machine

Comment: can you please run `makemessages` again to see if `.po` files has been changed or not. Its possible that msg_id does not match anymore with new implementations of your code, or you might have used any tag(like <br/> or {{}}) which could prevent `gettext` to work properly

Comment: please have a look at [my code](https://bin.disroot.org/?211411d5f0b11eb9#5NTgOMptVxXWaVmLt1KbpXFj8MWeHfTAuHotEbLeTLc=)

Comment: when i run makemessages already updated things also get changed

Comment: from your code, I don't think you need to put any translation in template with `{% blocktrans %}`. You can remove that.

Comment: do i need to use trans